# Checking for open ports in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming

There have been [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765235/checking-a-local-tcp-port-is-not-open-in-java) regarding the subject of verifying the accessibility and accessibility of socket ports.

How would one go about looking for a port to listen on dynamically in C/C++?

The basic process I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. Client starts
2. Client finds open port XYZ and listens on it.
3. Client transmits a basic 'I Am Here' message via UDP Datagrams to a server with the port information
4. Client and Server can communicate.

I know you can accomplish something like this if you pick an arbitrary port number and try [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)ing to it.  If it fails, increment the number and try again until you get a successful 'bind'.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  It seems kind of hacky.

Comment: Sending port numbers inside the message will break clients behind a NAT firewall, so don't do it. Just have the server use the port that the message arrived from.

Comment: @David Windows right now, but hopefully it will eventually be portable to linux as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you bind to port 0, a random port will be allocated.  Then `getsockname()` may be used to find out the actual port used.

Comment: That will work. But Sean, do not send the port number in a UDP message. That will break NAT. Just have the server respond to the port that the message arrived from.

Comment: @Zan NAT isn't going to be an issue.  It's only going to be used between elements on the same network segment.

Comment: +1 this is also used by FTP servers when client is in passive mode